# Different jar versions in during compile - Gradle Project(Both in IntelliJ and Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, gradle, jar, multi-module

I have a multi-module project where I am using Gradle. There is one module, Data, where I have dependencies for Neo4J. It uses lucene-core - version 3.6.2 underneath.

I am using this module as a dependency in another module, oe where I am using Jena-Text -version 1.1.2, which uses lucene-core version 4.6.1. Now, I had a conflict, so I ran the dependencyInsight plugin for Gradle, and excluded the dependencies for Neo4J in the oe module, because I don't need them there. The code compiles fine with gradle in lucene version 4.6.1.

Problem is, whenever, I'm trying to code in the oe module, I get auto-complete suggestions from lucence 3.6.2, but when Gradle eventually compiles it, it does it in the corect version, which is 4.6.1.

As for example, I want to write my own Analyzer in Lucene. The way you can write an analyzer has changed from version 3.6 to 4.6. Now it becomes difficult to code, if my IDE keeps telling me, I am writing a wrong code, based on a jar which I'm eventually not going to use. And this is happening both in IntelliJ Idea 13, Enterprise Edition and Eclipse Luna.

This is how I had excluded them.

```
compile(project(":data")){
    exclude group:'org.springframework.data', module: 'spring-data-neo4j-rest'
    exclude group:'org.springframework.data', module: 'spring-data-neo4j'

}
```

This is the result of running depedencyInsight for lucene-core in my oe module.

```
/oe$ gradle -q dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency lucene-core
org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:4.6.1
+--- compile
+--- org.apache.jena:jena-text:1.1.2
|    \--- compile
+--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:4.6.1
|    +--- compile
|    \--- org.apache.jena:jena-text:1.1.2 (*)
+--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:4.6.1
|    \--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:4.6.1
|         \--- org.apache.jena:jena-text:1.1.2 (*)
+--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:4.6.1 (*)
\--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:4.6.1
 \--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:4.6.1 (*)

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)
```

Comment: in intellij, you can prioritize which jar it uses by clicking up/down arrows on the dependencies tab for the module in the project structure. Not ideal but should fix the code completion issue

Comment: Doing what you said, solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: May be you should post that as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: Rats, we have the same problem, but in our case, the correct version we asked for isn't even in the list, so we can't just reorder the libs to get a working setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `intellij`, you can prioritize which jar it uses by clicking up/down arrows on the `dependencies` tab for the module in the `project structure`. Not ideal, but should fix the code completion issue.